# Difference between Kernel ridge regression and normal regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, kernel-trick

I wanted to ask whether they're any difference between Kernel Ridge Regression and normal Ridge Regression. I've fitted a dataset with both models and obtained approximately the same root mean squared errors for both methods. I know Kernel allows us to calculate the design matrix using a closed form and can be computationally quicker but wanted to ask whether in practice there's any difference between the two?

Comment: The point of kernel regression is not to calculate a design matrix using a closed form, but rather to expand the space of functions that can be well-approximated by the regression in a principled way.   If the true function is close to linear, kernel ridge regression will buy you very little, if anything.  See the answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49557/kernel-ridge-regression-efficiency?rq=1 for more.

Comment: Ah okay I understand.  So I’m not doing anything wrong if I get the same results for both kernel and ridge right ?

Comment: Well, you might want to check that your kernel function actually worked, and constructed a design matrix the way you thought it was going to!