# What is the difference between kernel function and kernel trick?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

My question is regarding the SVM topic.

What is the difference between kernel function and kernel trick? Are they same and refer to the same thing?

Comment: When you say "kernel function," are you asking about Parzen–Rosenblatt kernel density estimation methods, or something else?

Comment: hello @Sycorax. I am referring to the kernel functions used in SVM. I need to know if the concept of kernel function and kernel trick refer to the same thing or they are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel function is a function $K(x_1,x_2)$ which follows a few properties: in general it's the inner-product between $x_1,x_2$ in a higher-dimensional space. The kernel trick involves using such functions to treat inner-products between observations in the spaces described by the kernel function.

For SVMs and other kernelizable algorithms (linear regression, PCA, K-means, etc) the interest is in defining a higher dimensional kernel space (even infinite dimensional) while keeping the complexity of the problem at circa $\mathcal O(n^3)$ (see [Kernel Ridge Regression Efficiency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49557/kernel-ridge-regression-efficiency)).